# Overflowing grid item with fixed aspect-ratio

Tags: css, css-grid

I have the following requirements for a popup:

- The size of the popup is defined by its children.
- The `large` child needs to be reasonably large to make sure the content can actually be read.
- The `square` child just needs to be square.

I also want to make them the same height, to make it look cleaner. The result should look like this:

[image: Goal]

However, in the following snippet, setting `height: 100%` does not make the popup wider, it just makes the square item overflow the popup. How can I fix this?

```css
.popup {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  grid-gap: 0.5rem;
  
  background-color: pink;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  translate: -50% -50%;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.popup > * {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.large {
  min-width: 150px;
  width: 50vw;
  min-height: 100px;
  height: 30vh;
}

.square {
  height: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
}
```

```html
<html style="height: 100%">
<body style="height: 100%; margin: 0; position: relative;">
  <div class="popup">
    <div>hi</div>
    <div class="large"></div>
    <div>hello</div>
    <div class="square"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have a possible workaround, but I feel it is not very clean:

```css
.popup {
 --large-height: clamp(100px, 30vh, 10000px);
}

.large {
  height: var(--large-height);
}

.square {
  height: 100%;
  width: var(--large-height);
}
```

Edit: interestingly, the current result is slightly different between chrome/edge and firefox:

Chrome:
[image: chrome/edge]

Firefox:
[image: firefox]

Comment: Is the square actually overflowing or is large just being prevented from growing by `height: 30vh;`?

Comment: Not a solution but I could identify that width of area filled by background-color is only as if it is `grid-auto-flow: row`.

Answer (score -1):

I wrapped `.popup` in `.popup-wrapp`. And added

```css
.square {
   aspect ratio: 1;
   min-height: 100%;
}
```

It seems to work as you need now:

```css
.popup-wrapp {
  position: fixed;
  display: grid;
  inset: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.4);
  z-index: 666;
  padding: 1rem;
  overflow: auto;
}

.popup {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  grid-gap: .5rem;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: pink;
  padding: .5rem;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.popup > * {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.large {
  min-width: 150px;
  width: 50vw;
  min-height: 100px;
  height: 30vh;
}

.square {
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="popup-wrapp">
  <div class="popup">
    <div>hi</div>
    <div class="large"></div>
    <div>hello</div>
    <div class="square"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: not exactly, no. I want `large` and `square` to have the same height. see the updated question

Comment: I have updated my answer. It seems I misunderstood your question at first.

Comment: This works in chrome/edge, thank you. It does however not work in firefox.

Comment: On further inspection, all i need for it to work in chrome is changing `height: 100%` to `min-height: 100%` for the `.square` class. In firefox this sadly has no effect.